# Scanf crashing after first successful call

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have written below code for scanning two 3x3 matrix and printing them ,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void scanmat(int **arr)
{
    int i=0, j=0 ;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",((*arr+i)+j));
            printf("%d-%d\n",i,j);
        }
    }
}

void printmat(int **arr)
{
    int i=0, j=0 ;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",(*(*arr+i)+j));
        }
    }

}

void main ()
{

    int a[2][2], b[2][2]  ;
    scanmat (a);
    printmat(a);
    scanmat(b);
    printmat(b);
}
```

`scanmat(a)` and `printmat(a)` gose well, but when control reaches `scanmat(b)` , i am getting segfault.

Below are my system details,

```
6_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)
```

On analyzing core i find below,

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000003496056470 in _IO_vfscanf_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003496056470 in _IO_vfscanf_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003496063c6d in __isoc99_scanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004005d4 in scanmat (arr=0x7fff57041de0) at scanmat.c:10
#3  0x0000000000400842 in main () at scanmat.c:
```

appreciate any suggestion , what could be possible reason for crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
int a[2][2], b[2][2];
```

Thus, your matrices are only 2x2, so you overwrite memory which causes undefined behavior.

Remember that in a C array declaration, `a[N]` gives you an array `a` with `N` elements. The indexing is 0-based, so valid indices range from 0 up to but *not including* `N`. A suitable way to iterate through such an array is

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

in other words, the number of elements in the array `N` is the exact same value that you should use in the loop's condition, as long as you remember to

- Start from zero
- Compare using `<`

I also really don't think you can pass an `int[2][2]` to a function that expects `int **`, are you sure you're not getting compiler warnings for those calls?

Comment: yes , i am getting compiler warnings for that.... , can you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[2][2], b[2][2]  ;
```

And, while looping

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
```

0 to 3 means, 0, 1, and 2. But your array has space for only two elements  `0` and `1`.

```
int a[3][3], b[3][3];
```

would fix it